# Using BabelWay as an Enterprise Service Bus alternative?

Tags: .net, integration, biztalk, esb, eai

Our company is looking for a solution to simplify the integration of third party systems. We have done a lot of research and we are aware of the many Enterprise Service Bus solutions that are available. However, solution like Microsoft’s BizTalk Server provide too much functionality, and are to complex four our needs.

We found a solution called **BabelWay** (http://www.babelway.com/) that does exactly what we want, however it is quite expensive. So, before committing to this solution we would like to know if anyone knows any alternatives that provide about the same functionality? This would help us a lot  allow us to make a better choice for our solution.

For those that do not know BabelWay it is a integration service in the cloud that provides user to the ability to easily communicate with third party systems that use different communication protocols and data formats. To do this it provides a simple and user-friendly web UI that allows users to visually create transformations and configure the different communication options.

So, we are looking for an alternative that provides about the same functionality with the same simplicity.
It can, but does not have to be a solution in the cloud.
A .NET based solution would be an advantage for us, but it is not a must

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am from Babelway. We have also done lots of research and we don't know of any comparable service (but you are of course not obliged to believe me!)

Solutions we are usually compared with are Boomi and Cast Iron (but these are more suited for EAI and SaaS application integration, although they claim they also work for B2B). 
In B2B, we don't know of any other multi-tenant SaaS platform except maybe messagexchange.com which you could check.
In the standard software category, there is BizTalk (as you mention), Axway, Sterling and many, many others.

I think you'll find they are more complex and more expensive than Babelway.

There are a few open source alternatives for EDI, which you'll find via Google. That would be free but it will take time and functionalities you need might not be all there. You'll have to bear yourself the costs of hosting, monitoring, certificates, the network communication costs (depending on which protocols you want to support), upgrades, etc.

I don't know if you already talked directly to us but, if not, don't hesitate to do so. I really liked your analysis of our service but I am surprised about the perception of being expensive, since we're trying hard to make it very very competitive. Anyway, I'd be really interested to know what your search leads to.

Regards.